# Add line breaks to a long string in R - Tidyverse soultion?

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have a long string and want to add line breaks in a systematic way. I want to add the line break after Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018. Regardless of what comes after. Is there perhaps an elegant `tidyverse` solution?

```
string <- "2120002122;Arboga Kommun ;Arboga kommun, Vuxenutbildningen;Specialistundersköterska inom demens;415723rb;1984;Arboga Kommun;Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 20182120001561;Borås Kommun;Borås Stad - Borås Yrkeshögskola;Automationsingenjör;525523fa;1490;Haglund Industri AB;Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 20181"
```

Comment: You mean literally adding line breaks, not splitting it into a vector?

Comment: Is it always the string ```Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018```? If yes, you could always try ```gsub( "Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018", "Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018\n", string)```?

Comment: Since you asked for `tidyverse` solution, you could do: `str_replace(string, pattern = "Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018", replacement = "Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018\n")`. `str_replace()` belongs to `stringr` package wich is part of `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_split` and positive lookbehind:

```
library(stringr)
str_split(string, "(?<=Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018)")
[[1]]
[1] "2120002122;Arboga Kommun ;Arboga kommun, Vuxenutbildningen;Specialistundersköterska inom demens;415723rb;1984;Arboga Kommun;Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018"
[2] "2120001561;Borås Kommun;Borås Stad - Borås Yrkeshögskola;Automationsingenjör;525523fa;1490;Haglund Industri AB;Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018"             
[3] "1"
```

Use `unlist`to get a vector:

```
unlist(str_split(string, "(?<=Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018)"))
```